# Find the area of the hyperbolic (geodesic) triangle with vertices (0, 0),(0, 1) and (1, 0).

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, noneuclidean-geometry

I'm not really sure where to start for this question. I'm aware of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem $Area = \pi -(A+B+C)$ where $A,B,C$ are the interior angles of the triangle. However I am not sure how to go about calculating these angles given the vertices.

Comment: Where do these points live? Apparently in neither the hyperbolic half-plane nor the hyperbolic disk. So what's your model for the geometry?

Comment: @TedShifrin could be a doubly ideal triangle in the disc

Comment: @WillJagy: Indeed, *could* be ... Could be doubly ideal in the half-plane, too, for that matter.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the points lie in the hyperbolic upper half-plane.

Comment: @martinhynesone: Well, two of them are on the "boundary," not in the upper half-plane, so this is what's called a (doubly) ideal triangle. So draw the geodesics "joining"  the three points and figure out the angles from the picture. In the case of the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$, those will the points at infinity on the geodesics. [Hint: Two of the angles will be $0$.]

Comment: @martinhynesone You have a piece of paper and a compass and straightedge?

Comment: LOL, @Will, I think a piece of paper and pencil will suffice. And knowledge of what curves are the geodesics.

Comment: @Ted, I keep hoping that someone will make an app for tablet that will replicate drawing on graph paper. The tablet shows squares and the student can adjust the squares per inch. Then there is an stylus that can write, place points, draw curves, but meanwhile the tablet does not do any drawing or calculating. This is on account of I don't see actual graph paper making a comeback, but I would really like the kids to have an active part in creating various graphs

Comment: So the 2 angles which are 0 would be the angles at (0,0) and at (1,0), as they are on the border / are ideal points?

Comment: And the final angle would be 45° / pi/4? So the area of the triangle would be 3/4 pi?

Comment: How did you arrive at $\pi/4$?

Comment: I attempted to graph the triangle for more information but apparently didn't do a very good job of it!

Comment: You know what geodesics are ... you need to figure out which three you have here.

Comment: The geodesics in this case are a vertical line from (0,0) to (0,1), a half circle from (0,0) to (1,0), meaning the angle at (0,0) is 0, but the final one is where I am uncertain. Is it the quarter circle centered at (0,0)? If so, the angles would be 0, 0, and pi/2 meaning the total area is pi/2?

Comment: Yes, you need a semicircle perpendicular to the $x$-axis passing through $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. I believe $\pi/2$ is correct.